# Detecting a symbol in DataGridView Cell

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am trying to Append a `column` (GST) of my `DataGridView` with a Percentage `symbol` (%) .

**For Ex.** If a user enters `18` it should automatically turn to `18%`

```
Private Sub DataGridView2_CellEndEdit(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView2.CellEndEdit                        
    If DataGridView2.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("GST").Value IsNot Nothing Then
    DataGridView2.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("GST").Value = 
    DataGridView2.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("GST").Value + "%"                    
 End If
End Sub
```

I achieved it like this. But now the problem I am facing is every time the cell gets edited, adds one more % symbol even if it already have.

So it looks Something like this `18%%` , if user enters the cell and leaves again `18%%%`

If anyhow I am able to detect the percentage symbol, I could add such condition in `if` clause. If % is present there no adding it again.

Comment: You should format that Cell's value instead of setting it. See the [CellFormatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting) event, with some attention to [DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellformattingeventargs) properties (more specifically `e.Value` and `e.FormattingApplied`).

Comment: Your approach is wrong (see @Jimi) but `DataGridView2.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("GST").Value.Trim("%".ToArray()) + "%"`

Comment: @Jimi I used what you mentioned and yes it works. If you could put it properly in the answer section so that I can mark it as `answer`. It will help others too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should format that Cell's value instead of setting it. See the `CellFormatting` event, with some attention to `DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs` properties

(more specifically e.Value and e.FormattingApplied)

Note: Answered by Jimi in comments section

Answer (score 0):

Format that cell's value instead of setting it. See the [CellFormatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting?view=netframework-4.8)  event for more details.